PowerShell formatting of netdom query fsmo into a simple HTML report
Gurus, I'm struggling with PowerShell formatting of the command netdom query fsmo into a simple HTML report.  Right now, everything is left justified into cells in the left column and what I have been banging my head to do is put the results into the cells in the right column (those are in Green, off to the right).  No matter what I tried everything just stays in the left-hand column cells!
The current code:
# Execute 'netdom query fsmo' command
$fsmoOutput = netdom query fsmo

# Split the output into lines and remove empty lines
$fsmoLines = $fsmoOutput -split "`r?`n" | Where-Object { $_ -ne '' }

# Start adding a new table for FSMO roles
Add-Content $report "<table width='100%'>" 
Add-Content $report "<tr bgcolor='LightSteelBlue'>" 
Add-Content $report "<td colspan='2' align='center'><B>FSMO Roles</B></td>" 
Add-Content $report "</tr>" 

# Add four line breaks
Add-Content $report "`r`n`r`n`r`n`r`n"

# Iterate over each line of FSMO output to create HTML table rows
foreach ($line in $fsmoLines) {
    # Split the line into FSMO role and server
    $fsmoRole, $fsmoServer = $line -split ":"

    # Add table row with FSMO role and server
    Add-Content $report "<tr>"
    Add-Content $report "<td bgcolor='GainsBoro' align='left'><B>$fsmoRole</B></td>"
    Add-Content $report "<td bgcolor='Aquamarine' align='left'><B>$fsmoServer</B></td>"
    Add-Content $report "</tr>"
}

# Close the table for FSMO roles
Add-Content $report "</table>"

What the current output looks like:

Do you notice the small green boxes on the right hand side?  Those are what I want the output in!  This shouldn't seem hard, but it is!  Thanks gurus!

Can you show us what such a line from $fsmoLines looks like exactly? By the way, all those Add-Content commands are a waste of time.. Better gather all HTML formatted lines as string array and save the report in one go at the very end.

Thanks for the tidbit.  But as an AD engineer rather than an HTML artisan I got it working using all the Add-Content.  I wouldn't know how to do it asa string array, but thanks anyway!

The output from netdom query fsmo doesn't contain any colons (:), so $line -split ":" will always return 1 string.
Split on successive whitespace characters instead:
$fsmoRole, $fsmoServer = $line -split "\s{2,}"

